# Table body doesn't occupy full table width

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using twitter bootstrap for a responsive design that contains a table with four columns. I want the table columns to have equal widths, so I have set `td width` to 25%.

I would think that the table rows would inherit their size from the table, and the table cells would then each be one quarter of that. This seems to work when the device width is 768px or greater. When the device width is smaller, the rows are sized based on the text in the largest cell, as opposed to the size of the parent table.

I have included some sample code below, with background coloring on the different elements to highlight the error (made apparent by resizing the window horizontally). The errors are highlighted in yellow (where the underlying table colour is visible).

Live example: http://pastehtml.com/view/cqrwl31z2.html

I have tested in Chrome and Safari.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Table Test</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <style>
        td, th { width: 25% !important; }
        table { background-color: yellow; }
        tr { background-color: gray; }
        th { background-color: aqua; }
        td:nth-child(1) { background-color: red; }
        td:nth-child(2) { background-color: green; }
        td:nth-child(3) { background-color: blue; }
        td:nth-child(4) { background-color: purple; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <div class="row">       
            <table class="span12">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>A</th>
                        <th>B</th>
                        <th>C</th>
                        <th>D</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                    <tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <table class="span12">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Longer Table</th>
                        <th>Headers In</th>
                        <th>This</th>
                        <th>Table</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                    <tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i see your example  but what you want?

Comment: That is odd. I see it in Firefox, too.

Comment: @Pawan What I would like is for the table cells to take up the full width of the table. That way you would see no yellow. (You only see this yellow at smaller device sizes.)

Comment: Give 100% width to table. It should work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
[class*="span"], .uneditable-input[class*="span"], 
.row-fluid [class*="span"] {
   display: table;
}
```

---

Maybe it's not a good idea to use grid classes on a table. Instead, use .span12 on a wrapper div and set the table to `width: 100%`.

Comment: Thanks! both suggestions work. I think I will go with the second suggestion as unintended implications seem less likely.

Answer (score 3):

Put a width on your table.

http://jsfiddle.net/nEeKQ/4/

```
table {
background-color: yellow;
width:100%;
}
```

Comment: The problem is with the OP's original implementation of Bootstrap. Your example doesn't address this.

Comment: @isherwood You still can't expect the cells of a table to display widths correctly when the table itself has no width. The bootstrap issue was not really the problem, although, it was a poor implementation. Your own second answer proves that. For what it's worth I up'd your answer.

Comment: Like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure any parent containers have the width set at `100%`, in addition to the table having either an attribute `width="100%"` or `style="width:100%"`.

Answer (score 0):

When you zoom or the device width becomes greater the specified width it has no space to expand as width is given as % and not as px,so the best way to overcome this is to use 
  `min-width:100px` 
for the td or th which will be the minimum width it will take even when the device width exceeds.